Поиск однокоренных слов в списке через функцию, цикл и условие
возникла проблема с заданием, не могу понять, где ошибка. Задача звучит так:

Объявите функцию single_root_words и напишите в ней параметры root_world и *other_words.
Создайте внутри функции пустой список same_words, который пополнится нужными словами.
При помощи цикла for переберите предполагаемо подходящие слова.
Пропишите корректное относительно задачи условие, при котором добавляются слова в результирующий список same_words.
После цикла верните образованный функцией список same_words.
Вызовите функцию single_root_words и выведете на экран(консоль) возвращённое ей занчение.

import re


def single_root_words(root_word, *other_words):
    same_words = []
    for i in other_words:
        if i in other_words:
            re.search(root_word, i)
            same_words.append(i)

    return same_words
result = single_root_words('rich', 'richiest', 'orichalcum', 'cheers', 'richies')
print(result)
result2 = single_root_words('Disablement', 'Able', 'Mable', 'Disable', 'Bagel')
print(result2)


single_root_words - это калька с русского однокоренные слова?

Для выполнения задачи необязательно использовать модуль re.
Создаём функцию single_root_words(root_word, *other_words). Внутри создаём список (по условию задачи). Далее через цикл for перебираем слова на предмет наличия одинакового корня, для этого можно воспользоваться строковым методом, который вернёт нам True, если слово начинается с указанного префикса. И это метод - startswith(). Затем однокоренные слова помещаем в массив и возвращаем его.
def single_root_words(root_word, *other_words):
    same_words = []
    for word in other_words:
        if root_word.startswith(word) or word.startswith(root_word):
            same_words.append(word)
    return same_words


print(single_root_words('rich', 'richiest', 'orichalcum', 'cheers', 'richies')) 
# ['richiest', 'richies']


print(single_root_words('Disablement', 'Able', 'Mable', 'Disable', 'Bagel'))
# ['Disable']



Но здесь подходит только для первого списка

начинается с этого, поэтому подходит, а вот во втором нужен корень внутри слова able

Исправил ответ.

Должны выделяться и Mable, и Able. У меня в этом и возникла сложность. Не хватает знаний

Для того чтобы слово Able вывелось надо ещё перевести слова в нижний регистр через .lower(). А Malbe почему должно выводиться? Оно же вообще не содержится в слове.

Mable - там есть able

Замените тогда условие на такое: if root_word.lower().count(word.lower()) or word.lower().count(root_word.lower()):

Вроде оно, только Mable не видно почему-то. А можете объяснить использование count?

Метод позволяет подсчитывать количество вхождений заданной подстроки в строку.

Функция cognets принимает корень слова первым аргументов и слова-кандидаты в остальных аргументах. Слово считается однокоренным если оно содержит корень в себе как подстроку. И корень и слова приводятся к нижнему регистру:
def cognets(root, *words):
    cognets = []
    for w in words:
        if root.lower() in w.lower():
            cognets.append(w)

    return cognets


print(cognets('rich', 'richiest', 'orichalcum', 'cheers', 'richies'))
print(cognets('Disablement', 'Able', 'Mable', 'Disable', 'Bagel'))


$ python cognets.py
['richiest', 'orichalcum', 'richies']
[]


cognets имеет смысл переписать в виде списочного выражения. Питонисты такое любят:
def cognets(root, *words):
    return [w for w in words if root.lower() in w.lower()]

